# USB 2.0 fusing for protection

Tags: voltage, ground, protection, short-circuit

I'm reading about the ways to protect my electrical DIY projects that are power supplied by USB 2.0 cables (computer/chargers). Now...there are solutions for over voltage protection with diagrams that look like mazes. I'm planning to be simple and to cut the cable, cut the 4 wires inside, and install 4 500 mA fuses.
As it is clear to me that the fuses cost money, they also cost less than the project they guard. By ignoring that, is this a reasonable way to protect my projects (it looks at least plain simple to do), or these 4 fuses might cause some USB issues that are not obvious?

The only problem I see is if the GND fuse burns first, maybe not to fuse it, but fuse all other 3 wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they only cause obvious problems and it provides no protection to USB devices, but just the wires in the cable.

First one is, as you mentioned, plugging in a load that takes more than 500mA, for example a hard drive when it spins up or a mobile phone that can charge at 1A or 2A. It might blow the 5V fuse first, which is safe, but it might blow the ground fuse, which is not safe, as the return current path could be via ESD protection through data pins. So it might then cause current to flow via data wires.

Also if you ever encounter a situation where 500mA or more will flow through a fuse on data pin, the data port is likely damaged long before the fuse blows.

The USB data pair is a differential pair with specific impedance. If you cut the data wires and insert fuses, you are making a discontinuity in the data pair impedance, which causes reflections and may cause data transmission erros.

Not to mention any non-zero DC resistance a fuse adds to the wire.

Comment: That means that if I make a fuse only on the 5 V wire it shall provide me with some protection, right?

Comment: It depends on what you want to protect and from what. The USB host that sources power, USB device that consumes power, or the wires that transfer power. If you accidentally for example connect 12V to the 5V USB wire, both your laptop and device gets damaged before the fuse blows.  Usually USB hosts are already fused with polyfuses or overcurrent protection chips, so simply short circuiting 5V from USB to ground would not require extra fuses.